# Единицы измерения width и height в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Всем салам, я пытаюсь написать свою программу с tkinter. Но я никак не могу понять в какой единице измерения задаётся размер button(width и height) и как его перевести в px. Мне нужна максимальная точность, чтобы соблюсти симметрию интерфейса.

```
from tkinter import *

class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        button = Button(root, bg = "black", width = "10", height = "10")
        button.place(relx = 0.0, rely = 0.0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.geometry("1300x600")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вы можете указать размер в пикселях даже для текстовых кнопок, но это требует некоторого волшебства.  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm

Answer (score 5):

Здравствуй, сейчас объясню в чем проблема.

Проблема в том что когда ты задаешь width и height при вызове объекта tkinter,

```
Label (root, text='1', bg='#00ff00', font='Verdana 11', width=20, 
height=20).place(x=5, y=10)
```

то размер этого объекта будет зависеть от размере шрифта.
Например если указать font = 'Verdana 11' и width=20 и height=20 объект будет меньше чем
при font='Verdana 25' и width=10 и height=10. Проще говоря это указывается высота и ширина в символах объекта,  width = 10 - 10 букв в длину, height = 10 - 10 букв у высоту.
А когда задавать высоту и ширину методом place, вот пример:

```
l = Label (root, text='2', bg='#ff0000', font='Verdana 11', width=20, 
height=20)
l.place(x=50, y=50, width=20, height=20)
```

То тогда высота и ширина будут задаваться в пикселях.
Надеюсь, еще актуально.